# Change button style from default bootstrap

Tags: datatables

I am new to development. I need help with changing the appearance of Export to Excel and Clear filters buttons on some of the pages using Bootstrap. Can someone help me with this.

Attached images of buttons how they appear now (the one in grey color) and how they need to appear (the top one). As per the newest version of bootstrap, it appears grey in color (the one in grey color). But I need to change it to earlier version as in top image.

I am using the below code for exp to excel button:

buttons: [
{
extend: 'excelHtml5',
text: ' Export to Excel',
className: 'btn-sm btn_size',
titleAttr: 'Export to Excel',
exportOptions: {
columns: tableId === '#tblPDM' ? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] : [1, 2],

Thank you

Rajagopallan[Button Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhfSM.jpg)

I tried adding $.extend(true, DataTable.Buttons.defaults before the datatable initialization but it didn't work. i would like some simple solution that I can understand and use it in my code, as I am new to development